# In angular js, how do I show angular-loading bar with ui-router and ocLazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angularjs-routing

**Problem** : I am not able to load the angular-loading-bar using lazy load and ui.route.

Am I missing something ?

This is how my config.lazlyload.js file looks like :

```js
// lazyload config

angular.module('app')

// oclazyload config
.config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider',
    function($ocLazyLoadProvider) {
        // We configure ocLazyLoad to use the lib script.js as the async loader
        $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
            debug: false,
            events: true,
            modules: [{
                name: 'ngGrid',
                files: [
                    'vendor/modules/ng-grid/ng-grid.min.js',
                    'vendor/modules/ng-grid/ng-grid.min.css',
                    'vendor/modules/ng-grid/theme.css'
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'angular-loading-bar',
                files: [
                    'vendor/modules/angular-loading-bar/loading-bar.min.js',
                    'vendor/modules/angular-loading-bar/loading-bar.min.css'
                ]
            }]
        });
    }
]);
```

This is my config.router.js :

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Config for the router
 */
angular.module('app')
    .run(
        ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
            function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
                $rootScope.$state = $state;
                $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
            }
        ]
)
    .config(
        ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
            function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                $urlRouterProvider
                    .otherwise('/access/signin');
                $stateProvider
                    .state('access.test', {
                        url: '/test/me',
                        templateUrl: 'tpl/test.html',
                        controller: 'testController',
                        resolve: {
                            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                                function($ocLazyLoad) {
                                    return $ocLazyLoad.load('ui.select', 'angular-loading-bar').then(
                                        function() {
                                            return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/controllers/test.js');
                                        }
                                    );
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    })
            }
        ]
);
```

My controller is :

```js
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams) {

        //assuming this should start the loader
        $scope.start();

        var path = 'js/app/largeJson.json';
        var mails = $http.get(path).then(function(resp) {
            return resp;
            //this shall end the loader
            $scope.complete()
        });

    }
]);
```

Comment: you mails function should be `var mails = $http.get(path).then(function(resp) {
             $scope.complete()
            return resp;
        });` show complete should be call before returning data

Answer (score 1):

You complete function will never get called because you returned a data then you wrote `$scope.complete()`, you should write that `$scope.complete()` function before returning data.

**CODE**

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams) {

        //assuming this should start the loader
        $scope.start();

        var path = 'js/app/largeJson.json';
        var mails = $http.get(path).then(function(resp) {
            //this shall end the loader
            $scope.complete();
            return resp;
        });

    }
]);
```

**Update**

if you wish to use the loading bar without the interceptor, you can do that as well. Simply include the loading bar service as a dependency instead of the main `angular-loading-bar` module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['cfp.loadingBar'])
```

Then your controller will have the `start` & `complete` methods which will internally call `cfpLoadingBar` methods

**Controller**

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', cfpLoadingBar,
    function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, cfpLoadingBar) {

        $scope.start = function() {
          cfpLoadingBar.start();
        };

        $scope.complete = function () {
          cfpLoadingBar.complete();
        };
        //assuming this should start the loader
        $scope.start();

        var path = 'js/app/largeJson.json';
        var mails = $http.get(path).then(function(resp) {
            //this shall end the loader
            $scope.complete();
            return resp;
        });

    }
]);
```

For more info take a look at [**Github page**](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but that's not the real problem. The problem is I am getting undefined error for $scope.start(). How do i tell angular js that i have already declared ngProgress in ocLazyLoad config and also I have specified its name in config.router ?

Comment: could you please tell what erroe you are getting in console?

Comment: It says : Cannot read property 'start' of undefined at $scope.start()

Comment: @user3825003 where start & complete methods are defined?

Comment: They are actually inside angular-loading-bar.js. I have specified the path in config itself. So it should be able to find it out.

Comment: @user3825003 Do you read their github page? how they are implementing?